# Wordpress Admin page Error 404

Tags: 404-error

I am not getting the Wordpress Admin login page. It is displaying Error 404 Not found.
Can anyone help me exactly what could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by some conflict in theme or plugin.

Try renaming plugins folder. Some plugin might be causing this issue. 
If it works, try to find out by renaming each plugin at a time. 
Deactivate the plugin which is causing issues.

Do the same with themes if renaming plugins do not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an issue caused by an error in a plugin or theme.
Firstly, using FTP, rename your `plugins` folder to `plugins.old` or anything you want and try and access the admin dashboard again. If this works, rename the folder back and then reactivate plugins one at a time until it breaks.
If this doesn't work, rename your-theme folder in `wp-content/themes/your-theme` to something else which will automatically re-activate the default theme (assuming you still have it in your themes folder). Try and access the dashboard again.

If neither of the above doesn't work and you have recently moved the folder of your install or made some other file changes, then ensure you delete any cache storage.